# Submit using python mechanize with input tpe="image"

Tags: python, authentication, submit, web-scraping, mechanize

I want to click/submit a button which is of type image

`<input type="image" onclick="javascript:return showhide();" src="IMAGES/login.gif" name="submit">`

I tried the following

```
mech = mechanize.Browser(factory=mechanize.RobustFactory())
mech.open(url)
mech.select_form(nr=0)
mech["username"] = options.user
mech["password"] = options.pswd
results = mech.submit().read()
```

But still the results contains only the login page. How to emulate the clicking of submit whose type is image using python mechanize.

Comment: Can you provide the website URL you want to submit?

Comment: @iMom0 That's an internal URL which is not available externally.